# How to upload my training data into google for Tensorflow cloud training

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I want to train my keras model in gcp.

My code:

this is how I load the dataset

```
dataset = pandas.read_csv('USDJPY.fx5.csv', usecols=[2, 3, 4, 5], engine='python')
```

this is how i trigger cloud training

```
job_labels = {"job": "forex-usdjpy", "team": "xxx", "user": "xxx"}
tfc.run(requirements_txt="./requirements.txt",
        job_labels=job_labels,
        stream_logs=True
        )
```

Right before my model, which shouldn't make much of a difference

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, 4)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Everything is working, docker image for my model is being created, but the *USDJPY.fx5.csv* file is not being uploaded.
So I get *file not found* error

What is the proper way of loading custom files into the training job?
I uploaded the train data to s3 bucket but I wasn't able to tell google to look there.

Comment: Did you try Cloud Storage? Put your file there, and change the file location with the prefix `gs://<YOUR BUCKET NAME>/pah/to/file.csv`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes it worked, it was a permission/visabiliy issue with the bucket. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with my GCP configuration
Here are the steps I made to make it work:

- Create an s3 bucket and make all files inside it public so the train job can access them
- Include these two in the requirements fsspec and gcsfs
- remove the 'engine' parameter from panda.readCsv like so

  dataset = pandas.read_csv('gs:///USDJPY.fx5.csv', usecols=[2, 3, 4, 5])

Since you are uploading the python file to GCP a good way to organize your code it to put all of the training logic into a method and then called it conditionally on the cloud train flag:

```
if tfc.remote():
    train()
```

Here is the whole working code if someone is interested

```
import pandas
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import tensorflow_cloud as tfc
import os

os.environ["PATH"] = os.environ["PATH"] + ":<path to google-cloud-sdk/bin"
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "<path to google credentials json (you can generate this through their UI"


def create_dataset(data):
    dataX = data[0:len(data) - 1]
    dataY = data[1:]
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)

def train():
    dataset = pandas.read_csv('gs://<bucket>/USDJPY.fx5.csv', usecols=[2, 3, 4, 5])

    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
    scaler = scaler.fit(dataset)

    dataset = scaler.transform(dataset)

    # split into train and test sets
    train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
    train, test = dataset[0:train_size], dataset[train_size:len(dataset)]

    trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train)

    trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, 4)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(4))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1000, verbose=1)


job_labels = {"job": "forex-usdjpy", "team": "zver", "user": "zver1"}
tfc.run(requirements_txt="./requirements.txt",
        job_labels=job_labels,
        stream_logs=True
        )

if tfc.remote():
    train()
```

NOTE: This is probably not an optimal LSTM config, take it with a grain of salt